# Textbox in loop how to remove after adding it

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputgaveabonnement">
      Gaveabonnement <b>*</b>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="fieldrow_horz">
        <div class="fieldgroup">
          <label>
            Gaveabonnement tekst <b>*</b>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldgroup">
          <label>
            utm_source <b>*</b>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
    // Save to array so that we can loop it out later =)

            $result = db2_getsub( array('campaigns_id' => $this_id) );

            if (!is_null($result))
            {
      $numsub = 0;
                while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() )


                {
        $numsub = $numsub +1;
        array_push($arrFornavn, $row->sub_name);
                array_push($arrEtternavn, $row->sub_code);
                }
      $formcountfld=$numsub;
            }
    else
    {
    $numsub=1;
    $formcountfld=1;
    }

        $i = 1;

        if (1==1) {

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numsub; $i++)
            {
    ?>
      <div class="fieldrow_horz">

        <div class="fieldgroup">
          <input type="text" id="fornavn_<?= $i ?>" name="fornavn_<?= $i ?>" value="<?= $arrFornavn[$i-1] ?>" />
        </div>

        <div class="fieldgroup">
          <input type="text" id="etternavn_<?= $i ?>" name="etternavn_<?= $i ?>" value="<?= $arrEtternavn[$i-1] ?>" />
        </div>

      </div>

      <?php

                }

        } else {

    ?>

      <div class="fieldrow_horz">

        <div class="fieldgroup">
          <input type="text" id="fornavn_<?= $i ?>" name="fornavn_<?= $i ?>" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="fieldgroup">
          <input type="text" id="etternavn_<?= $i ?>" name="etternavn_<?= $i ?>" value="" />
        </div>

      </div>

      <?php

        }

    ?>
      <?php
                $thisId = "countfld";
                $thisVar = $formcountfld;
            ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="<?= strtolower($thisId) ?>" class="input-medium" id="input<?= $thisId ?>" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($thisVar, ENT_QUOTES) ?>" />
      <p>
        <a href="#" id="linkAdd">+ Legg til flere</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#linkRemove").click(function(){
        $("#fornavn_<?= $i ?>").remove();
        $("#etternavn_<?= $i ?>").remove();

            });
          });
```

How can i remove textbox after addding it through loop if anybody can help thanks 
in advance this code is adding textbox after clicking on + Legg til flere this but if want 
to remove textbox  can you suggest me how can i remove a textbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `jquery` you can remove an element by simply calling `remove()`;

```
 $("#fornavn_1").remove();
```

This is obviously done from the client side, your question doesn't specify where the removal has to be done from. If you want to remove it before sending to the browser it self. Then you may need to enable output buffering and parse the html with a dom parser and remove the element.

To use jquery make sure you include the following, `preferably` in the head section of your html.

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: i want to remove it before submitting

Comment: before submitting the form?

Comment: you can use the jquery solution i suggested for it

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#linkRemove").click(function(){
        $("#fornavn_1").remove();   its not working
   });
          });

Comment: can you update your question with the javascript code with a snippet from generated html

Comment: you can't use the php variable `$i` in there.

Comment: then how will i get the value of $i